# Mac takes too much storage space, calls it other

Tags: hard-drive, mac, storage

I have installed apps like **Cleanmymac**, and **Grandperspective** to delete this folder called **other** which takes up 78.82GB space on my mac  but none of these apps have been able to do that. Moreso, I can't access this folder directly, so I don't know the content of this folder.

> I will be glad if anyone can help me with a command-line or app that can view and remove this folder

Comment: 'Other' isn't a folder. It's any data that cannot be categorised.

Comment: Is there a way I can view these data and remove them from my mac

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5353/how-can-i-figure-out-whats-slowly-eating-my-drive-space

Comment: Thanks, going through it